# Multipage jQuery image gallery

Tags: jquery, image, gallery

Is there any jQuery gallery, which support multipages? My problem is, that every page contains different number of images. I'm using Lightbox 2, but i can't see any way to configure the gallery with multipages.  I can create 5-6 static HTML Pages, one page can contains one image gallery, but i think, this is not the perfect solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CmdrTallen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74071/cmdrtallen) just posted a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538101/javascript-or-jquery-for-background-image-slideshow/1538159#1538159) to [Gallerific](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/minimal.html).
It supports multipage solution as seen in the demo.

> Super simple to implement you just put your images in a Unordered List (UL) (in the example below the "thumbs-min" is the UL) and then do something like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {                              
    // Initialize Minimal Galleriffic Gallery
    $('#gallery').galleriffic('#thumbs-min', {
    imageContainerSel:      '#slideshow',
    controlsContainerSel:   '#controls'
    });
});
```

Comment: Galleriffic is a great solution for this. Easily coded, and easily maintained. Good call.

Comment: and how can i set the different number of images for each page? I see only the numThumbs parameter, but this is for all pages....